# How to call the 'read' system call with python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, system-calls, fuse

I need to run the linux 'read' system call with my arguments. Any ideas?

```
read(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,struct fuse_file_info *fi)
```

I need to call the above function with my arguments.

Comment: **Why** do you need to call the read system call? Do you have a filehandle already?

Comment: I'm building a testing script for a FUSE program and I need to check if the 'read' works correctly.

Comment: A regular Python `open()` call into the mounted filesystem would work just fine. If you used Python to implement the FUSE plugin and you are building a unittest, then just call the Python implementation directly without bothering with actually firing up FUSE to drive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python exposes [the C stdlib `read()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) as the [`os.read()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.read):

> **`os.read(fd, n)`**
>   Read at most *n* bytes from file descriptor *fd*. Return a string containing the bytes read. If the end of the file referred to by *fd* has been reached, an empty string is returned.

Errors are raised as `OSError` exceptions, with the `errno` attribute set to an integer as documented in the C `read()` documentation. You could use the [`errno` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno) if you wanted constants to test against.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know how I specify the flags I want to read with?

Comment: @ifryed: What do you mean, 'flags'? That's not an argument you can pass to the C-level `read()` function.

Comment: @ifryed: are you confusing the 'read' function implemented by a FUSE plugin with the system read call, perhaps?

Comment: I think I did mix them up, I edited the question

Comment: That is indeed *not* the Linux `read()` function (I linked to the man page in my answer). You are basically asking how to test an arbitrary API, coded in whatever user-space language you coded your plugin in. If it is in Python, there is *no need to call a C function*.